What should it be if the treatment group is larger than control groups in Propensity-Score-Matching (PSM) -DiD
In an effort to do Difference-in-Differences (DiD), to mimic the Randomized Controlled Trials, we normally use the Propensity Score Matching (PSM) to eliminate the difference between control and treatment groups before the event date.
Normall we will have a small treatment group and big controll groups and we just follow the original steps.
But today i faced something different:
When I try to examine the impact of a laws A on all listed firms in Australia, I should compare the impact of this law A on firms in Australia compared to firms in New Zealand (NZ) during the same period (because New Zealand not implement the law A during that period)
And the fact is that Australia has more firms than NZ, meaning the treatment group is bigger than control groups.
I have tried to matching 1:2, 1:3 and the matching is failed (there is difference from treatment and control grousp atfer matching). Only the matching 1:1 works well.
After running the regression with the matching 1:1, I still find that the law A has significant impact on firms in Australia compared to firms in NZ (by using DiD)
I am wondering my setting with 1:1 is acceptable because it means that not all Australia firms will be matched in the matched sample due to the lask of NZ firms.

Discarding valid data is not scientific in my opinion, an PS matching is extremely inefficient.  More here.

The only matching method that requires the treated group to be smaller than the control group is pair matching without replacement. There are so many other matching methods you can use. That said, there are so many better methods than matching for satisfying conditional parallel trends; see the did package for examples.
